# Cocoapod error right after installing successfully

Tags: cocoa, xcode5, cocoapods

I installed CocoaPods :

```
retine:MacOS jdmuys$ sudo gem install cocoapods
[...]
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.29.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-0.29.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for cocoapods-0.29.0...
```

However, it doesn't seem to work:

```
retine:MacOS jdmuys$ pod --version
/Users/jdmuys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find cocoapods (>= 0) amongst [addressable-2.3.2, bundler-1.2.3, chunky_png-1.2.6, compass-0.11.7, cookiejar-0.3.0, daemons-1.1.9, em-http-request-1.0.3, em-socksify-0.2.1, erubis-2.7.0, eventmachine-1.0.0, extlib-0.9.15, fssm-0.2.9, haml-3.1.7, http_parser.rb-0.5.3, json_pure-1.4.6, rack-1.4.1, rake-10.0.3, rubygems-bundler-1.1.0, rvm-1.11.3.5, sass-3.1.21, sproutcore-1.9.1, thin-1.2.11, thor-0.14.6] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/jdmuys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /Users/jdmuys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
from /Users/jdmuys/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

FWIW:

```
retine:MacOS jdmuys$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode51-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer
```

(doesn't help if I switch to a non beta version of Xcode)

and

```
retine:MacOS jdmuys$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

Any idea what is happening and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried restarting Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, and re-installing without sudo – `gem install cocoapods` – fixed the issue for me.